# iOS 13 UNNotificationAction button not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, action

Actions fail to show.

And, they also fail to show with these downloaded notification demo apps
 - LocalNotifications by Bart Jacobs
 - RemindMe by Keith Harrison (Use Your Loaf)
 - EatMoreVegetable by Brian Advent

Interestingly, I can make action button appear by doing this:
Step
1) In app, fire notification request
2) Leave app - go to Home screen
3) Notification appears without action button
4) Drag notification down causes action button to appear
Same results with simulator or device.

My demo app can be downloaded from here
https://github.com/tricarb/UNLocalDemo

```
func registerCategories() {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let actionID = Notify.actionID.rawValue
    let categoryID = Notify.categoryId.rawValue

    let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: actionID, title: "Action Title", options: [.foreground])
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: categoryID, actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [])
    center.setNotificationCategories([category])
}

func fireNotification() {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Content Title"
    content.body = "This is the content body"
    content.categoryIdentifier = Notify.categoryId.rawValue

    let timeInterval = TimeInterval(7)
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("Notification will fire in", timeInterval, "seconds")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get action button to show you need to swipe the notification to the left (in notification center). There you'll see three buttons: "Manage", "View", "Clear".

Select "View" and you'll get the same behavior as you have when you drag down the notification that just appeared.